# get property from object using enum value from loop

Tags: c#

In one file there are enums as follows:

```
public enum RelativeFatLevels
{
    Low,
    Medium,
    High
}
```

There is a Component class in a separate file like so:

```
public class Component
{        
    public Enum RelativeFatLevel;
    public double Fat;
    // other properties here
}
```

There is a FormulaOutput class in a separate file that acts like a container to hold Component objects for a formula:

```
public class FormulaOutput
{
    public Component Low { get; set; }
    public Component Medium { get; set;}
    public Component High { get; set;}
}
```

In a separate unit testing file I am trying to build a generic method to replace this logic:

```
private FormulaOutput GetDifferences(FormulaOutput app, FormulaOutput test)
{
    FormulaOutput container = new FormulaOutput();

    Component componentDifferencesLow = new Component();
    componentDifferencesLow.RelativeFatLevel = RelativeFatLevels.Low;

    Component componentDifferencesMedium = new Component();
    componentDifferencesMedium.RelativeFatLevel = RelativeFatLevels.Medium;

    Component componentDifferencesHigh = new Component();
    componentDifferencesHigh.RelativeFatLevel = RelativeFatLevels.High;

    container.Low = componentDifferencesLow;
    container.Medium = componentDifferencesMedium;
    container.High = componentDifferencesHigh;

    return container;
}
```

This is a pared down version - there are several properties in Component that need to be set which are not shown above (they were removed to make the code snippets more readable).

Below is what I've tried.  The lines that are commented out are not working.  I'm stuck on how to proceed from here.  Note that the file does include `using System.Reflection;` so I don't think that's the issue.  Also, the code to add the component to the container object doesn't exist yet - not sure how to write that either.

```
private FormulaOutput GetDifferences(FormulaOutput app, FormulaOutput test)
{
    FormulaOutput container = new FormulaOutput();

    foreach (RelativeFatLevels relativeFatLevel in Enum.GetValues(typeof(RelativeFatLevels)))
    {
        Component componentDifferences = new Component();
        //componentDifferences.RelativeFatLevel = test.Low.RelativeFatLevel;
        //componentDifferences.RelativeFatLevel; 
        //PropertyInfo xyz = test.GetType().GetProperty(relativeFatLevel.ToString()).GetValue(test, null);
        //PropertyInfo abc = typeof(FormulaOutput).GetProperty(relativeFatLevel.ToString()).GetValue(test, null);
        //Type type = typeof(FormulaOutput);
        //var aaa = type.GetProperty(relativeFatLevel.ToString()).GetValue(test, null);
        //Component current = typeof(FormulaOutput).GetProperty(relativeFatLevel.ToString()).GetValue(test, null);
    }

    return container;
}
```

Comment: When you say _not working_, what exactly does happen?

Comment: what exactly do you want to do? and what is nt working?

Comment: `public Enum RelativeFatLevel;` should be `public RelativeFatLevels RelativeFatLevel`

Comment: What is it you wish to achieve with this system? Not sure I follow the idea.

Try to elaborate in pseudo code or words what your intentions are, as an addition to the code you display.

Comment: I want to write a generic line to replace `componentDifferencesLow.RelativeFatLevel = RelativeFatLevels.Low;' and
 'componentDifferencesMedium.RelativeFatLevel = RelativeFatLevels.Medium;` 
and
 'componentDifferencesHigh.RelativeFatLevel = RelativeFatLevels.High;`.

Comment: What're `app` and `test` parameters, and what do you want to do with them?

Comment: `app` and `test` are objects passed into this method that will be used in logic that hasn't been written yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
// create container
FormulaOutput container = new FormulaOutput();

foreach (RelativeFatLevels relativeFatLevel in Enum.GetValues(typeof(RelativeFatLevels)))
{
    // create component
    Component component = new Component();
    component.RelativeFatLevel = relativeFatLevel;
    component.Fat = CalculateFatFromRelativeFatLevel(relativeFatLevel);

    // look for property on the container with the same name as the fat level
    var property = typeof(FormulaOutput).GetProperty(relativeFatLevel.ToString());
    if (property != null)
    {
        // assign the component to that property
        property.SetValue(container, component);
    }
}

return container;
```

Note: Your enum should be called `RelativeFatLevel` (singular) since it represents a single value.

Comment: To add to your last comment, page 59 of *Framework Design Guidelines*, section 3.5.3 says:  "**Do** use a singular type name for an enumeration, unless its values are bit fields."

Comment: @poke Brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against a method that tries to enumerate over properties.  It will actually make your code harder to maintain by adding extra layers to it.  There are times where it makes sense to assign properties by iterating over them, but this is not one of those times.

Instead, I would make a method that generates a `Component` for you, and just invoke it 3 times.

```
public Component GenerateComponent(RelativeFatLevel level)
{
    var result = new Component();
    result.RelativeFatLevel = level;
    result.Fat = CalculateFat(level);
    //set other properties here.
}

public double CalculateFat(RelativeFatLevel level)
{
    //todo
}
```

...

```
container.Low = GenerateComponent(RelativeFatLevel.Low);
container.Medium = GenerateComponent(RelativeFatLevel.Medium);
container.High = GenerateComponent(RelativeFatLevel.High);
```